# Pass value of selected item of dropdown in PHP

Tags: php, html, selectlist

I have a html form and getting usernames from database in middle of that form with php, i want to submit select option value when user click on button.

File1 :

```
<link href="users_forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="rightcolumn">
    <form method="post" action="user_remqry.php">
        <br />
        <legend> Remove Users </legend>
        <fieldset>
            <br />


            <?php
            include'connect.php';
            $q=mysqli_query($con,  "SELECT username FROM users_allow");

            echo "<select name=uname_selected''  ><option value=0>Select a username</option>";
            WHILE($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
            {
                echo "<option name='uname_remove' value=$row[username]>".$row[username]."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            ?>


            <br /> <br /> <br /> <input type="submit" value="Delete User" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

### File 2(user_remqry.php):

```
<?php
$uname = $_POST["uname_selected"];
echo 'I am going to remove =  '.$uname;
?>
```

I just want to pass value of the selected item of select list.

Comment: List showing username from database

Comment: You don't need to add the name attribute to every option in your select. You can just name the select and the variable `$_POST["uname_selected"]` should contain the selected value.

Comment: thanks for help, i got my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few things to be changed in your code

```
include 'connect.php'; //please add space
$q=mysqli_query($con,  "SELECT username FROM users_allow");

echo "<select name='uname_selected'>"; //note the position of single quote
echo "<option value='0'>Select a username</option>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['username']."'>".$row['username']."</option>"; 
} //don't have to put name attribute at the option. Put quotes around $row['username']. Note the single quote surrounding the username
echo "</select>";
```

as Jerodev mentioned, no need to put name for the option. On the next page, just need to call name of the select. In your case `$_POST['uname_selected']`

Comment: Thanks for help, its working now, these single quote and double quotes and really a terrible thing when searching for human errors.

Comment: Glad to help. That's a normal thing to miss due to human error. Please consider to mark it as answer if it helps :-)

Comment: kindly mark my question as good because its a genuine problem